# Difference in DOCTYPE's

Tags: html

I am new to HTML concepts, but I had issue with my web page. It was not able to load properly on IE10 then I googled further and changed the doctype from

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

to

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

surprisingly it worked

I tried reading regarding this DOCTYPE got to know that the mentioned DTD is used to render the web page. But i was not able to gather much information. can anyone tell me what is actually making the difference there ??

Comment: The good news is you should pretty much only worry about the very nice `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">` is a quirks mode giving doctype. What doesn't work in IE10?

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` is the correct standard doctype for HTML5. There's no good reason to use any other doctype for HTML in today's web.

Comment: @Alohci has pinpointed the *real* key issue here; the reason the old doctype was causing problems. If it was forcing the browser into Quirks mode, then it's going to be messing up all kinds of things with your layout. Quirks mode is an emulation mode for the way IE5 rendered HTML. If you want your page to look like its 1997, have some ugly bugs and only work at all in IE, then use Quirks mode. If you don't, you should avoid quirks mode at all costs. And the way to do that is to make sure you have a valid modern doctype.

Answer (score 3):

According to HTML standards, each HTML document requires a document type declaration. The "DOCTYPE" begins the HTML document and tells a validator which version of HTML to use in checking the document's syntax.

Doctype you used earlier :-

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

as you can see belongs to html 4

and doctype you used later

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

is HTML 5. the latest standard for web. That's why it's working in IE10.

Comment: But the same is working for IE9 and Edge... its just not working for IE10

Comment: I don't know the reason but if you are looking for solution to make it work  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh779632.aspx this might help.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is HTML 4.01 and HTML 5. The doctype for HTML 5 is simply:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

There could be many different reasons for why the rendering is different. For a well formatted HTML 4 document there shouldn't be any difference between HTML 4 and HTML 5. But if you are using HTML 5 features then declare the document as HTML 4 you may be triggering quirks mode.

"Quirks" mode is what browser manufacturers call when they need to emulate features of older versions of the browser engine including bugs (yes, emulate bugs, because some web developers use bugs to trigger features in their code). You can think of quirks mode as HTML version custom-to-this-browser-and-only-this-browser.